# Send .wav file from python to React JavaScript

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, wav

I'm creating .wav files in my Python script and aiming to transmit these files to my ReactJS frontend via localhost, but I am unsuccessful. How can I do this? Or is there a better way? The idea with the app is for the users to generate audio on the server and then listen to it.

In my python script i send the .wav file like this

`return send_file(wav_filename.wav, as_attachment=True)`

and

```
const renderWithData = async (t, min, setGenText) => {
    try {
      const fetch_url = "http://" + uri + `/create?topic=${t}&min=${min}`;
      const response = await fetch(fetch_url);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
      const audio = new Howl({
        src: [audioURL],
        format: ["wav"],
        autoplay: true,
        onplayerror: function() {
          console.error("Error occurred while playing the sound.");
          setGenText("Error occurred while playing the sound.");
        },
        onend: function() {
          console.log("Finished playing the sound");
          setGenText("Audio file received and played successfully.");
          // Perform other actions here
        },
      });
  
      // Play the sound
      audio.play();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching or playing the audio file", error);
      setGenText("Error fetching or playing the audio file.");
    }
  };
```

and i recieve this error

`Error fetching or playing the audio file [TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined]`

and I've tried a bunch of different ways and received different errors. most of them seems to complain about the audio in ReactJS.